# How to add background color and foreground color using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, button, checkbox

the program is to click a colour and select if you want background or foreground then click 'change color' button it works that how it should be but while clicking the value from the variable `buttonValue` is not coming out of the function.

the value from button value is not coming out please help. The console says the error is

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="background">background</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="foreground">foreground</input>
<input type="button" value="change color" id='run'>
```

**JS:**

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];

for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.innerText = colors[i];
    button.value = colors[i];
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    button.addEventListener('click', change);
    document.body.append(button);
}

var buttonValue;

function change(g){
    buttonValue = g.target.value; 
}   

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click',AlertMe);

function AlertMe() {

  document.getElementsByName('check').forEach( (el) =>{
    
    alert(buttonValue);
    if(el.checked === true){
        if((el.value) == "background")
        {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = buttonValue;
        }
        else if((el.value) == "foreground")
        {
          document.body.style.color = buttonValue;
        }
        
    } 
    
  });
 
}
```

Comment: It is working as expected, What is it that is not working...

Comment: it looks like the classic mistake of putting the HTML code in the Header of your page ...

Comment: thank you for the answer i did'nt think it would be this easy i was looking at the javascript code from top to bottom many times it was my home work assignment thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working properly as long as you put the code in the header.